Сокеты, C++ и boost asio
Пытаюсь разобраться с тем как работают сокеты. Использую библиотеку boost asio, и все никак не пойму до конца некоторых моментов:
Допустим, было успешно установлено TCP соединение, открыт сокет. Теперь я хочу "сделать запрос к серверу" и отправить некую порцию данных:
template<typename P>
void send_with_payload(Socket& socket, const P& payload)
{
    // Общий размер запроса
    const auto len = sizeof(Header) + sizeof(P);

    // Заголовок
    buffer_copy(buffer_->prepare(sizeof(Header)), boost::asio::buffer(&header_, sizeof(Header)));
    buffer_->commit(sizeof(Header));

    // Полезная нагрузка
    buffer_copy(buffer_->prepare(sizeof(P)), boost::asio::buffer(&payload, sizeof(P)));
    buffer_->commit(sizeof(P));

    // Писать в сокет (покуда не будет записано всё)
    boost::system::error_code error;
    write(socket, *buffer_, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(len), error);
    if(error.failed())
    {
        buffer_->consume(buffer_->size());
        throw std::runtime_error(error.message());
    }

    buffer_->consume(len);
}

И уже на этом моменте возникает вопрос:
Строка boost::asio::transfer_exactlyпо сути является условием прекращения. Это значит запись в сокет будет продолжаться покуда указанное кол-во байт не будет "записано". Но что вообще означает записано? Это значит на другой стороне это было прочитано? И покуда прочитано не было - поток блокируется? (именно это показывает практика, но я не уверен - корректное ли это поведение) Или же чтение на другой стороне вовсе не обязательна в этот же момент, и данные все равно отправятся, но будут находится "подвешенном состоянии" у сервера в сокете (порочесть их можно когда угодно, а клиент не ждет пока сервер их прочтет)? А может возможны оба варианта?
Второй момент (на стороне сервера). Насколько правильно "читать несколько раз", при том что запись была единожды? Например:
В начале читаем первую часть данных из сокета:
void receive(Socket& socket
    , const TypeBits& types
    , const Operation& op = Operation::O_UNKNOWN)
{
    // Читаем ТОЛЬКО заголовок (чтение прекращается когда получен его размер)
    boost::system::error_code error;
    read(socket, *buffer_, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(sizeof(Header)), error);

    auto* data = const_cast<void*>(buffer_->data().data());
    header_ = *static_cast<Header*>(data);

    buffer_->consume(sizeof(Header));
    header_received_ = true;
}

Второй раз читаем отсавшуюся часть (основываясь на полученных при первом чтении данных определяем размер оставшейся части)
template<typename P>
class RequestWithPayload final : public Request
{
public:
    explicit RequestWithPayload(Request* base)
    : base_(base)
    {}

    ~RequestWithPayload() override = default;

    void receive_payload(Socket& socket) override
    {
        // Читаем "полезную нагрузку" (чтение завершается когда получен размер полезной нагрузки)
        boost::system::error_code error;
        read(socket, *buffer_, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(sizeof(P)), error);
        
        auto* data = const_cast<void*>(buffer_->data().data());
        payload_ = *static_cast<P*>(data);
        buffer_->consume(sizeof(P));
    }

    const P& payload()
    {
        return payload_;
    }

protected:
    P payload_;
    Request* base_;
};

То что я пытаюсь сделать (одна запись - два чтения) - не работает (сервер повисает на втором чтении и бесконечно ждет), и я не уверен, то ли потому что это принципиально неправильно для сокетов (и всякий раз когда мы пишем, нужно все сразу и читать), то ли по каким-то иным причинам.
Буду рад развернутому ответу.
P.S.
Благодяря комментариям нашел ошибку, из-за которой сервер повисал на втором чтении. Все дело было в transfer_at_least при чтении. Нужно было читать фиксированный и точный размер (transfer_exactly). Но в целом заданные вопросы все еще актуальны:

Когда поток блокируется - чтобы его разблокировать, обязательно ли участие второй стороны (чтение отправленных данных)?
Если да, то какое именно? (прочесть всё/прочесть что-то/попытаться прочесть)
Если нет - каков критерий разблокирования потока, в какой момент функция вернет управление?


А как tcp сокеты работают на уровне системных вызовов (описанных в manpages socket, sendto, recvfrom и т.п.) вы хорошо понимаете?

записано означает, что данные переданы сетевой подсистеме и можно записать еще что-нибудь, где они конкретно находятся - не известно. Раз в коде используются синхронные варианты вызовов, то естественно, что поток блокируется, пока вызов не вернется. "Читаем ТОЛЬКО заголовок" - там использована конструкция transfer_at_least, соответственно читается НЕ ТОЛЬКО заголовок, но и потенциально кусок данных неопределенной длины после него.

@user7860670 - поток блокируется, ок, но каков критерий его разблокирования? Ожидаем ли мы прочтения другой стороной (прочтения всего, прочения хотя бы чего-то, просто факта попытки чтения), или же нас другая сторона вообще не волнует?

@user7860670 - да, там transfer_at_least, по этой причине могут быть проблемы со следующим read (поскольку в первом read я мог отхватить больше чем ожидал)?

@avp, мое понимание сокетов довольно поверхностно. Как они устроены под капотом и на аппаратном уровне (какие биты передаются, какие сигналы бегут по проводам в те или иные моменты - мне неведомо). Я знаю что это пробел, устранением которого я собираюсь заняться, но на данный момент хочу разобраться как их использовать на программном уровне, в надежде на то что понимания в духе "штука в которую можно писать байты на одной стороне и читать байты на другой стороне" будет достаточно чтобы их использовать в коде. Осталось разобраться с нюансами о которых я собственно и спросил.

@AlexNem, собственно я написал этот комментарий, поскольку преграммировал разные сокетные программы на Си более 30 лет и ни разу не использовал никаких надстроек (кроме wget и т.п. в шелловской части). Как-то пытался попробовать boost (опять же, пытаясь поиграться с С++), но но быстро понял, что "овчинка выделки не стоит" (может они уже исправили мелкие, но весьма принципиальные в редко встречающихся ситуациях ляпы, но всякое желание иметь с ними дело отбили напрочь)

Поток блокируется, пока данные передаются сетевой подсистеме. Где они реально находятся при возврате, отправились ли уже, дошли ли уже - не известно.

@user7860670, ок, с блокированием при записи более менее ясно. А что в случае с чтением? Блокируем покуда там не окажется нужного кол-ва данных для прочтения?

@AlexNem, если без всяких библиотечных надстроек, то при чтении TCP сокета вы получите столько байт, сколько есть во входной очереди, но не более запрошенного количества. Блокируется чтение (если сокет не сделать неблокируемым (вызвав fcntl)) только если вообще ничего не прислали. Кстати, программируя TCP важно помнить, что это просто поток байт (никаких границ, связанных с разными вызовами send в нем принципиально нет) поэтому если вам нужно разделять "записи", то это надо делать на уровне вашего прикладного протокола

Такое ощущение, что вы не читали документацию к используемым методам. Откуда появляется вопрос "А что в случае с чтением? Блокируем покуда там не окажется нужного кол-ва данных для прочтения?", если третьим аргументов вы указали transfer_at_least, то бишь необходимость передать не меньше указанного объема данных. Еще стоит иметь ввиду, что вы не работаете с сокетами, вы работаете с библиотекой boost.asio. Принятый ответ и комментарии пользователя avp вводят в заблуждение. Функция read из этой библиотеки имеет принципиально иную семантику по сравнению c посиксным read.

@user7860670, дело в том что у меня не было понимания как работают posix сокеты в целом (без надстройки в виде boost::asio) и вопрос "блокируемся ли" больше о принципе работы сокетов вообще, а не конкретно boost. Коментарий в ответе, где была приведена аналогия в виде заполняемой трубы в целом ситуацию прояснил (подобного абстрактного представления мне пока хватает). По поводу отличий boost от posix - я исхожу из того что boost это надстройка, соответственно правила работы с сокетами в boost не должны сильно отличатся (просто могут быть какие-то доп. нюансы). Но могу ошибаться конечно


Когда поток блокируется - чтобы его разблокировать, обязательно ли
участие второй стороны (чтение отправленных данных)?

Строго говоря, не обязательно. А в некоторых случаях, получатель вообще ничего сделать не может, поскольку данные до его узла ещё не дошли (скажем, ограничитель трафика их поставил на небольшую паузу, или маршрутизаторы переключаются на резервную линию, а TCP ожидает повторную передачу пакета).

Если да, то какое именно? (прочесть всё/прочесть что-то/попытаться
прочесть)

Не что-то прочесть, а прочесть достаточно много. Грубо говоря, если при посылке запроса поток был заблокирован на первом байте, то если вторая сторона прочитает данные достаточные только для заголовока, то Вы и не заметите, что, возможно, поток был разблокирован и снова заблокирован, а возможно, его и разблокировать не стали (зависит от реализации, плюс оговорки выше).

Если нет - каков критерий разблокирования потока, в какой момент
функция вернет управление?

Если строго, то соответствующий вызов(ы) ОС (send()) успешно приняли все данные.

Это значит на другой стороне это было прочитано?

Нет. Для подтверждения другой стороной, что она что-то прочитала и/или поняла прочитанное, она должна прислать явное тому подтверждение.

Все дело было в transfer_at_least при чтении. Нужно было читать фиксированный и точный размер (transfer_exactly).

transfer_at_least() потенциально более эффективен, поскольку, в удачных случаях больших нагрузок, снижает количество вызовов ОС. Т.е. если ОС может сразу передать Вам в буфер не только заголовок, но вообще всё, то почему бы и нет? Только пользоваться этим надо правильно (может, ОС, что б дважны не вставать, 3,62 записи туда вернул). 

Хм, я запутался. Для разблокировки потока получение отправленного не обязательно, но при этом.. Не что-то прочесть, а прочесть достаточно много? Зависит от реализации сокетов именно на стороне операционки/компилятора? Судя по моим "экспериментам" при ЗАПИСИ сокет действительно не блокируется принимающей стороной, и я могу записывать несколько раз, но при ПОЛУЧЕНИИ сокет блокируется покуда не получится прочесть (а сколько необходимо прочесть - можно задать).

Грубо говоря, TCP соединение это длиная труба приличной ёмкости - от десятков килобайт до мегабайт (есть очереди отправки отправителя, есть очереди получателя). Отправка будет блокироваться, но при превышении этой ёмкости. Да, часто, особенно в тестах, самое узкое место - это получатель. Если труба заполнилась под завязку, то пока получатель чего-нибудь не получит, то в неё ничего и не послать. Но, строго говоря, в этой трубе могут быть и иные узкие места. К примеру, когда провайдер говорит - полоса 256 кбит/с, то если приложение попытается выдать больше, то тормозить его будет провайдер.
